# Why Intellij keep using Gradle 2.2

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am using Intellij IDEA (lastest version), when I create a new Gradle project (default gradle wrapper and customizable gradle wrapper) it always use 2.2 by default. I've set PATH to gradle 2.7.So why Intellij IDEA still use 2.2

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your source tree, run:

gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.13

(or whatever version you particularly want)

Then you'll need to re-import the project. Make sure to select "Use gradle wrapper task configuration" instead of the default gradle wrapper.